# can I omit there are

Tags: subordinate-clauses, existentials

I am having following construction,

> The extraction of outline becomes very difficult if ***there are***
>   very short boundary edges where very few laser points reside.

I feel it is possible to omit the words "there are" from the above sentence. is that so?

Comment: Short answer: No. An alternative could be something like: *The extraction of **an** outline becomes challenging if very short boundary edges **exist** where **scant** laser points reside.*

Answer (score 4):

You may not strike them, since that would leave your *if* clause incoherent.

Here's your structure (I've rewritten a little to make your phrases idiomatic):

> [<sub>MAIN CLAUSE</sub>
>   :   [<sub>SUBJECT</sub> **Extraction of the outline**]
>   :   [<sub>PREDICATE</sub>
>   :   :   [<sub>VERB</sub> **becomes**]
>   :   :   [<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub> **very difficult**]
>   :   ]
>   ]
>      [<sub>SUBORDINATE CLAUSE</sub>
>      :   [<sub>SUBORDINATOR</sub> **If**]
>      :   <strike>[<sub>SUBJECT</sub> **There**]</strike>
>      :   [<sub>PREDICATE</sub>
>      :   :   <strike>[<sub>VERB</sub> **are**]</strike>
>      :   :   [<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub> **very short boundary edges**]
>      :   :       [<sub>ADJUNCT</sub> **where very few laser points reside**]
>      :   ]
>      ]

As you see, *there are* has a critical role in the sentence. It cannot be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

No, 'there are' is required in the above sentence.

Also, you are missing a 'the' in the first phrase. 'The extraction of outline' should instead be:

> The extraction of the outline

or

> Extracting the outline

It might be a good idea to rewrite the sentence to something like:

> Extracting the outline becomes much harder if there are very short
>   boundary edges where only a few laser points reside.

This avoids using the word 'very' too much.

Just to let you know, the opening sentence could be:

> I am having difficulty with constructing the following sentence:

or something similar. As it stands, it's not grammatically correct.