# Omitting "there is"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

(I'm aware of the  [can I omit there are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11266/can-i-omit-there-are) question. Apart from the title, it doesn't look really similar to this one.)

Consider an excerpt from a grammar cheat sheet. The "comments" (which are given in *italic*) are a part of the cheat sheet itself.

> - The dog is young, well trained, and good natured.
> - The dog is young, well trained and good natured. - ***There is** no comma after "trained"*

> - The dog is young, well trained, and good natured.
> - The dog is young, well trained and good natured. - *No comma after "trained"*

The second example omits "there is".

- Is it a valid option to omit "there is" in special cases like cheat sheets or tables?
- Is it a valid option to omit "there is" in normal writing? (E.g., in novels and technical manuals.)

My primary interest is technical writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the style of these cheat sheets, but both comments *could* be understood to mean:

`There *should be* no comma after "trained"`

which, as I think you know, is debatable.

If the comments are simply intended to *point out the absence* of the second commas, it might have been clearer to say "Two commas" and "One comma", or "With a second comma", "Without a second comma".

To your first question I would say it is acceptable as long as the reader is familiar with the style of the cheat sheets and can tell the difference between a piece of advice and an observation.

To your second question: novels are very different from manuals (in my experience!). In *novels* any form of English is allowed. So "There is no water" and "No water" are both permissible. In *manuals* clarity and precision are as essential as in cheat sheets. [See above.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I do not see a "there is," in any of the example sentences.

If you are referring to the Oxford Comma, (comma used before "and"), the sentence is valid regardless of whether or not the comma is in place or not.

Personally, I use the Oxford Comma wherever possible, as the sentence tends to flow more smoothly.

Comment: See the first block, there is a sentence `There is no comma after "trained"`. My question is not about Oxford comma.

Comment: Apologies, your lack of a full stop makes it look like a side comment referring to the Oxford Comma. In this example, you should not omit the "There is."

Comment: Jeko, I think it would be better to delete this answer. It's completely irrelevant here.

Comment: It's irrelevant now that you edited your original post. Instead of being rude to the person who put the time together to answer your poorly put together question, try being nice.